# "breakpoint set but not bound" issue in Electron

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, electron

*VSC: 1.42.1

Electron: 8.0.3

macOS: 10.14.5

node: 11.15.0*

When trying to debug the `renderer` process in `Electron`, none of the breakpoints trigger due to the "breakpoint set but not bound" issue.

Breakpoints in the renderer worked in VSC 5 or 6 versions ago and then it broke in an update. I've been all over SO, the VSC github "issues" pages and none of the examples have helped. VSC debugging can't be broken for everyone.

My project structure is shown below as is the launch configuration I am using.

---

```
{
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
          {
              "type": "node",
              "request": "launch",
              "name": "Electron: Main",
              "protocol": "inspector",
              "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
              "runtimeArgs": [
                  "--remote-debugging-port=9223",
                  "."
              ],
              "windows": {
                  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
              }
          },
          {
              "name": "Electron: Renderer",
              "type": "chrome",
              "request": "attach",
              "port": 9223,
              "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
              "timeout": 30000
          }
      ],
      "compounds": [
          {
              "name": "Electron: All",
              "configurations": [
                  "Electron: Main",
                  "Electron: Renderer"
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
```

---

[image]